# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in Drools

Tags: java, drools

I am getting this error.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/drools/core/command/runtime/rule/FireAllRulesCommand

Even though the same code along with same jars works fine in my teammate's system. This class is present in **`drools-core.jar`** I am not sure why for me class is not found during run time. I have no additional logs. It just shows the mentioned error during debug.

Could you please guide me here.

Comment: are you running this application in web container such as tomcat or jboss?

Comment: Application runs on weblogic 12c. It calls drools rule engine hosted on JBoss BRMS.

Comment: check whether your weblogic lib has jar

Comment: Weblogic lib does not have this jar. I don't think it's needed there.  I have compared the test and dev instances it is not present. Anyway I try it once.

Comment: Thanks @kuhajeyan, it works now. Much Appreciated.